# A inequality in stability of mean curvature flow

Tags: inequality, mean-curvature-flows

$C_1,C_2$ are positive constants, and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is a constant too.

If for any $\epsilon>0$, we have 
$$
\sum_{i<j}(k_i-k_j)^2 \le C_1 \epsilon^{2\alpha}  \\
\sum k_i \ge C_2 \epsilon^\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$
How to show $k_i>0$ ?

This is my guess, when $\epsilon$ is small enough, the first inequality means the $k_i$s have little difference. Although the RHS of second inequality approached zero also, but it is of low order respect to $\epsilon^{2\alpha}$.

This question is origin from
*Lin, Longzhi; Sesum, Natasa*, [**Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00526-016-1003-x), Calc. Var. Partial Differ. Equ. 55, No. 3, Paper No. 65, 16 p. (2016). [ZBL1343.53064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1343.53064).

Comment: Please, recall the meaning of abbreviations you use : MCF = ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  This is from the stability of MCF.

Comment: This, you have said it in your title ! But what do the 3 letters MCF mean ? If I say you "I work on the ZAF theory", you would ask me the same...

Comment: @JeanMarie  Oh, sorry , I understand you , and edit it .

Comment: Are you sure you have the exponents of $\delta$ correct? As written this is false unless $C_1$ is small compared to $C_2$. Small $\delta$ doesn't help - making the substitution $\lambda_i = \delta^\alpha k_i$ makes this clear. Maybe it should be $C_1 \delta^{2+\alpha}$ and $C_2 \delta$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Seemly, there is not exponents of $\delta$. It is from the top of  12 page of  Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow. I add the link in above. Seemly, the author take same mistake in botton of 8 page and top of 9 page. I am not sure, I will read it detail.

Comment: I think you made a mistake - they have something like $H \ge C_2 \epsilon^{\alpha/2}$ and $|\overset \circ A| \le C_1 \epsilon^\alpha$, not $|\overset \circ A|^2 \le C_1 \epsilon^\alpha.$ Do you agree?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Yes, I made a mistake. I have edit it. The mistake is I blunder $H \ge C_2 \epsilon^{\alpha/2}$.  About second line, I think $\sum_{i<j}(k_i-k_j)^2 \le C_1 \epsilon^{2\alpha}$  is equal to $|\overset \circ A| \le C_1 \epsilon^\alpha$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after your edit this makes more sense - if we normalize by setting $a_i = \epsilon^{-\alpha/2}k_i$ then we have $$\sum_i a_i \ge C_2,\;\;\sum_{i<j} (a_i-a_j)^2\le C_1 \epsilon^\alpha.$$

Now we are in good shape - decreasing $\epsilon$ will force the $a_i$ closer together without changing the lower bound. Letting $\hat a = \max_i a_i$, note that we have $$\hat a \ge \frac 1 n \sum_i^n a_i \ge \frac{C_2}n$$
and
$$(a_i - \hat a)^2 \le \sum_{i<j}(a_i - a_j)^2\le C_1 \epsilon^\alpha;$$ so $$a_i \ge \hat a - |a_i-\hat a|\ge \frac{C_2}n-\sqrt{C_1 \epsilon^\alpha}.$$

Choosing $\epsilon$ small enough that $\sqrt{C_1 \epsilon^\alpha} < C_2/n$ completes the proof.